# Gradle: What is the proper way to specify the final spring-boot jar file?

Tags: docker, spring-boot, gradle

My spring-boot application was originally built with maven, but I'm trying to gradle-ify it. Part of my build process was making a docker image with the [dockerfile-maven](https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven) plugin. The most accepted gradle equivalent seems to be the [com.palantir.docker](https://github.com/palantir/gradle-docker), so that's what I'm using (at least according to [this tutorial from pivotal](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/).)

My setup is pretty simple. My dockerfile takes a build argument, which is the final jar, and adds it to the image.

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
MAINTAINER github.com/paul-nelson-baker
EXPOSE 5005 8080 35729
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Xdebug", "-Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=5005,suspend=n", "-jar", "/var/paulbaker/pauls-blog.jar"]
ARG JAR_FILE
ADD ${JAR_FILE} "/var/paulbaker/pauls-blog.jar"
```

The part that's getting me hungup is the gradle setup. The build arg that I pass appears correct:

```
docker {
    name = "paulbaker.io/my-blog"
    tags 'latest'
    dockerfile file('src/main/docker/Dockerfile')
    files "${project.name}-${version}.jar"
    buildArgs([JAR_FILE: "${project.name}-${version}.jar"])
}
```

However whenever I attempt to build the image, I get the following error even though the actual java build succeeds:

```
$ gradle build docker

> Task :docker FAILED
ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder952857277/pauls-blog-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar: no such file or directory
```

I've tried a myriad of combinations to try to specify the path (relative to my project) of `./build/libs/pauls-blog-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`, which I can see exists while the printed directory above does not.

There is clearly something I'm not understanding about gradle builds, can someone clear up how to get the final jar file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem, but I don't know why this is different, so I'm leaving the question opened so someone has a chance to give a detailed explanation as to why this works.

The correct values should be referencing `jar.archivePath`.
So the final result looks like this:

```
docker {
    name = "paulbaker.io/my-blog"
    tags 'latest'
    dockerfile file('src/main/docker/Dockerfile')
    files jar.archivePath
    buildArgs([JAR_FILE: "${jar.archiveName}"])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following error:

```
> Task :docker FAILED
ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder952857277/pauls-blog-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar: no such file or directory
```

happens when the Palantir Docker plugin cannot find the file specified using the docker.files attribute with respect to your current context directory.

In your question, the plugin was searching for the jar file in the root directory of the project (likely where your build.gradle is) and fails because the jar file is not generated there. When you specify jar.archivePath, you are specifying the full location of the path to the jar file which will now obviously be found.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to `files` are added to a gradle CopySpec of the docker task.

So `files jar.archivePath` adds that path where your jar build artifact was created to this *CopySpec*.

When your *Dockerfile* is processed, the `jar.archiveName` is inserted into the `ADD` template and because your `jar.archivePath` is in the *CopySpec* of the docker build context, it finds the `jar.archiveName` in the *CopySpec* and copies the file to the destination of `ADD`.

This is my take on what I'm seeing in my own testing.